# Why can't $\frac{1}{\not0}\cdot \frac{\not0}{1}=1$?

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers, fractions

I would assume that this question should have the obvious answer, that since $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined, this expression is undefined also.

However, given that we can solve arithmetical problems with arithmetically undefined quantities (as far as the real numbers are concerned) such as $i$ on the premise that it eventually cancels out, why can't we do something similar by simplifying the expression as $\frac{1}{\not0}\cdot\frac{\not0}{1}=1$?

Comment: think about it with limits: $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x}\cdot \frac{x^2}{1}=\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{x}{1}}=0$ but other way around will be $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x^2}\cdot \frac{x}{1}=\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{x}{1}}=\infty$ so this might help you.

Comment: Since $\frac01=0$, you want $\frac10$ to be a number which, multiplied by $0$, gives 1. That's impossible because any real number, multiplied by $0$, gives $0$.

Comment: Hello @ArielFishbein, This makes sense, since $0=0^2$ we induce a contradiction

Comment: "we can solve arithmetical problems with arithmetically undefined quantities" : can you clarify ? I don't think that anything in mathematics can be done with "undefined" quantities.

Comment: Do you agree $\frac01 = \frac02$?  What happens if we multiply both sides by your $\frac10$?  Note this doesn't mean we can't define an arbitrary $\frac10$, but rather if we do, we cannot keep all the same rules of arithmetic (likely, multiplication would no longer be associative, but I'm not sure it would be the only victim).  Most mathematicians find admitting a "$1/0$" of incredibly limited utility.

Comment: Hi @ArielFishbein. The fact that $1/0$ is conventionally left undefined has little to do with limits. In any field, $1/0$ is also left undefined; since fields do not in general have any analytical structure, this indicates that the reason that $1/0$ should be left undefined is *algebraic* in nature. The real reason that $1/0$ is undefined is that we want $a/b$ to mean $ab^{-1}$, where $b^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $b$. But $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse in any field; in particular, there is no real number $x$ such that $0\times x = 1$.

Comment: Hey @Joe. I gave him an example as to why this won't work. Do you agree with me that if it doesn't work for one example, then all other examples won't considered as true?

Comment: @ArielFishbein At best, your example is about continuity, not arithmetic, so the conclusion would be "we cannot use continuity to define this operation".  There are plenty of meaningful operations that aren't continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac 10$ is not like $i$. When you adjoin a square root of $-1$ to the reals, you get something bigger, namely the complex numbers. You *can* define a multiplicative inverse of $0$, but it's not very interesting. Let's see what happens.

Let's define $a$ to be the multiplicative inverse of $0$. Then $0a = 0 = 1$. For any element $r$ of this new algebraic structure, $r=1r=0r=0$. Hence it only has one element, which you can call either $1$ or $0$ as you choose. In this new structure,
$$\frac{1}0\frac{0}1=1$$
as you wanted, but we've lost everything to achieve this. It's not worth it.

Comment: Hi @MattSamuel, thanks for this answer, helps me to see the 'why' as much as the 'how'

Comment: @AlexanderPasha No problem.

Comment: It does feel a bit like cheating to hide the assumption it's a ring, though.  As a ring, sure, it collapses, but there are extensions in broader categories.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I'm not familiar with nontrivial ways to invert $0$ in other contexts. Perhaps you could write an answer detailing an example.